# Internal Hyperlinks within PDF getting removed after processing using PDFKit

Tags: swift, macos, pdfkit

I'm using the following code to draw a text over PDF page.Everything works fine, but if you process a PDF with internal links eg: a Book with Content links to pages, the resultant PDF file seems to have the links stripped off.Why does this happen?

```
                let data = NSMutableData()
                let consumer = CGDataConsumer(data: data as CFMutableData)!
                let context = CGContext(consumer: consumer, mediaBox: nil, nil)!
                let pdffile=PDFDocument(url: input)                   
                for y in stride(from: 0, to: pagecount, by: 1)
                {
                let page: PDFPage = pdffile!.page(at: y)!
                var mediaBox = page.bounds(for: PDFDisplayBox.mediaBox)
                NSGraphicsContext.current = NSGraphicsContext(cgContext: context, flipped: false)
                
                let bounds = page.bounds(for: PDFDisplayBox.mediaBox)
                let size = bounds.size                   
                page.draw(with: .mediaBox, to: context)
                text.draw(in:drawrect,withAttributes:textFontAttributes);
                context.endPDFPage()
                }
                context.closePDF()
                try! data!.write(to: GetOutputFileName(inputfile: x), options[.atomicWrite])
```

Comment: @KJ thanks but this talks about printing, I am not printing the PDF document but directly saving it to disc.

Comment: Does `page.draw()` draw links? And if it does, does it translate links to the new document? And if it does, are the linked pages in the new document?

Comment: @Willeke Actually I thought `page.Draw` automatically picks up links in the original page. Do I need do it manually?

Comment: If `page.Draw` doesn't add links then you will have to find a different solution.

Comment: @KJ I do not get your point.

Comment: @Willeke Solution other than `PDFKit` ?

Answer (score 3):

Links are just kind of annotations, so we need just re-add annotations from original pages to new pages, like

```
...
}
context.closePDF()

let anotherDocument = PDFDocument(data:data as Data)
for y in stride(from: 0, to: pdffile!.pageCount, by: 1)
{
    let page: PDFPage = pdffile!.page(at: y)!
    let newPage: PDFPage = anotherDocument!.page(at: y)!
    for anotatation in page.annotations {
        newPage.addAnnotation(anotatation)      // << here !!
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / macOS 12.5

[image: demo]

[Test module is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_macOS/PlayOn_macOS/Findings/TestPDFFileModification.swift)